# Making .env file dynamic in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a .env file with some keys that I want to make dynamic. So that I can use the same env file for all my servers and remove it from git. For Example

.env
ENV_TYPE: #myVariable

I want to fetch this value in **linux** from

```
echo MY_ENV = 'Test'
export MY_ENV
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you don't want something in Git, add it to `.gitignore`. All the frameworks that build React apps (eg `react-scripts`, Vite, etc) all look for `.env` files in the project root directory

Answer (score 2):

`.env` files are just one way of setting environmental variables. You can also set them at the command line, like so:

```
MY_ENV_VAR=5 node someFile.js
```

You can also use that syntax in the "scripts"  section of `package.json`. You can also set them permanently on a given computer by adding them to the `.bashrc` file (most Linux users) or `.zshrc` file (most Mac users).  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables for further details.

If you want a "dynamic" `.env` file, simply put the parts that don't change into that file, commit it into Git, and then use one of the other methods to set the variables that need to change.